# How to instantly know if payment was successful using recurring payments?

Tags: paypal-subscriptions

I am implementing recurring payments on a website through SetExpressCheckout and CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

Since it's being used for giving a user access to the member's area, I would need to know right away if the initial purchase was successful. Right now, CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile always returns 'Success' and profile status of 'Active' or 'Pending', and only through the IPN will I be able to know if the first transaction was successful or not. So the mechanism seems to be asynchronous (as opposed to Paypal's single transaction system).

Is there any way to know right away (synchronously) if the first payment is successful so that the website can let the member know if he/she has access to the member's area or do we have to tell the user that his/her access is pending verification or something like that?